# Scrollable Bar graph matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scrollbar

I am a newbie to python and am trying to plot a graph for some frame ids, the frame ids can vary from just about 10 in number to 600 or above in number. 
Currently, I have this and it works and displays 37 ids together but if I have suppose 500 ids, it clutters them and overlaps the text data. I want to be able to create it in such a way that in one go I only display first 20 ids and there is a scroll bar that displays the next 20 ids and so on..
My code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import numpy as np

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(100,2))

x=range(1,38)
y=[1]*len(x)

plt.bar(x,y,width=0.7,align='edge',color='green',ecolor='black')

for i,txt in enumerate(x):

   ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]))

current=plt.gca()

current.axes.xaxis.set_ticks([])

current.axes.yaxis.set_ticks([])


plt.show()
```

and my output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yVyi.png)

Comment: The code does not show any attempt to use a slider. You would have found out about sliders by searching for something like "matplotlib slider". Since this is your first question on SO, I still answered your question, but be aware that you need to show some effort to solve the problem when asking a question here. Also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib provides a [Slider widget](https://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html). You can use this to slice the array to plot and display only the part of the array that is selected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
import numpy as np

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

x=np.arange(1,38)
y=np.random.rand(len(x))

N=20

def bar(pos):
    pos = int(pos)
    ax.clear()
    if pos+N > len(x): 
        n=len(x)-pos
    else:
        n=N
    X=x[pos:pos+n]
    Y=y[pos:pos+n]
    ax.bar(X,Y,width=0.7,align='edge',color='green',ecolor='black')

    for i,txt in enumerate(X):
       ax.annotate(txt, (X[i],Y[i]))

    ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])

barpos = plt.axes([0.18, 0.05, 0.55, 0.03], facecolor="skyblue")
slider = Slider(barpos, 'Barpos', 0, len(x)-N, valinit=0)
slider.on_changed(bar)

bar(0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! This is very helpful! I will keep your point in mind!