# Is it possible make matplotlib slider for graphs axis?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plotly, matplotlib-widget

I explored and didn't find if its possible make slider to horizontal axis (specifically time axis for my case) with Matplotlib library. I mean something in style in this page:
[plotly slider](http://plot.ly/python/sliders/)

Comment: There is a [slider demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/widgets/slider_demo.html). Maybe you want to spend some more words on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have long time measurement, and sample is made every second. So i get dense data on the graph and can't analyze it properly. I would want add slider to the graph that will control the zoom i see on the graph, or slider that navigate along the timline axis (like plotly slider in the above link). In addition, this graph should be presented in ppt, so more "modern" slider is preferable.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791466/scrollable-bar-graph-matplotlib