# Graph scrolling using pyqt5 and malplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

[previous question (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143781/how-to-set-yaxis-tick-label-in-a-fixed-position-so-that-when-i-scroll-left-or-ri)

Here i want that when i move the scroll bar using  mouse it will not scroll the graph but when i leave the mouse then the graph will be updated. Here every time axis limit are updating but i want it will update the axis limit when i leave the mouse moving the scroll bar at a certain position.
 **Note :** Here y -axis trick label position will be fixed and it would be visible but value will update when i scroll the graph.and i also want that scroll bar will start from right position.

Here my program :

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import num2date, date2num
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ochl as candlestick
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pylab as pl
class MainWindow_code_serarch(object):

    def setup_code_serarch(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1070, 680)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(17, 30, 741, 13))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget1.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget1)
        self.verticalLayout1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout1.setObjectName("verticalLayout1")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(17, 10, 1040, 603))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(100,7.2), dpi=80, facecolor='k')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.draw()
        # self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget)
        # self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.canvas)
        # self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.axes, self.axes2 = self.figure.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)


        data = {
            'date': ['2018/10/29','2018/10/30', '2018/11/03', '2018/11/04', '2018/11/05', '2018/11/07', '2018/11/10', '2018/11/11','2018/11/12','2018/11/13'],
            'open': [8824,8824, 8726.31, 8642.14, 8531.51, 8630.25, 8602.50, 8640.22,8202.50, 8610.22],
            'high': [8858,8858, 8748.60, 8551.36, 8653.16, 8476.69, 8630, 8570.56 ,8602.50, 8640.22],
            'low': [8688,8688, 8743.67, 8550.76, 8449.50, 8631.83, 8602.18, 8743.22 ,8502.50, 8540.22],
            'close': [8820,8820, 8747.17, 8550.52, 8553., 8517.10, 8628.78, 8588.52 ,8602.50, 8640.22],
            'volume': [17759.56,17759.56, 120000.17, 18739.52, 38599.50, 16517.10, 17723.78, 15588.52 ,28602.50, 28640.22]
        }
        x = date2num([datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y/%m/%d').date() for d in data['date']])
        t= np.arange(len(data['date']))
        candle_trace = zip(t, data['open'], data['high'], data['low'], data['close'], data['volume'])
        candlestick(self.axes, candle_trace, width=.75, colorup='g', colordown='r')
        self.axes2.plot(t, [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9,6,6,9])
        self.axes.set_position([0.02, 0.37, 0.88, 0.6])
        self.axes2.set_position([0.02, 0.15, 0.88, 0.22])
        self.axes.tick_params(axis='both', color='#ffffff', labelcolor='#ffffff')
        self.axes.yaxis.tick_right()
        self.axes2.tick_params(axis='both', color='#ffffff', labelcolor='#ffffff')
        self.axes2.grid(color='lightgray', linewidth=.5, linestyle=':')
        self.axes.grid(color='lightgray', linewidth=.5, linestyle=':')
        self.axes2.yaxis.tick_right()
        self.axes.autoscale_view()
        self.axes2.autoscale_view()
        self.axes.set_facecolor('#041105')
        self.axes2.set_facecolor('#041105')
        # N = len(dates)
        self.axes.set_xticks(range(0, len((x)), 1))
        self.axes.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(d).strftime('%b-%d') for d in x])
        self.axes.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in x])
        self.axes2.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in x])
        self.canvas.draw()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 246, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.graphShowCode)
        self.step = .1
        self.setupSlider()

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        # self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))

    def setupSlider(self):
        self.lims = np.array(self.axes2.get_xlim())
        print("limit"+str(self.lims))
        self.scroll.setPageStep(self.step * 100)
        self.scroll.actionTriggered.connect(self.update)
        self.update()

    def update(self, evt=None):
        r = self.scroll.value() / ((1 + self.step) * 100)
        l1 = self.lims[0] + r * np.diff(self.lims)
        l2 = l1 + np.diff(self.lims) * self.step
        self.axes2.set_xlim(l1, l2)
        self.axes.set_xlim(l1, l2)
        print(self.scroll.value(), l1, l2)
        self.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MainWindow_code_serarch()
    ui.setup_code_serarch(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: output]

Comment: The [`QScrollBar`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qscrollbar.html) provides other events which you can use instead of `actionTriggered` that is used here. Check out which of them you want to connect your callbar to. In `setupSlider` you can set the inital limits to your liking.

Comment: Thank you sir . My problem half is solved by taking sliderReleased() action . Now how can i set the inital limits of my graph scrolling. How i can select last portion of the graph ?

Comment: You set the limits yourself via `self.axes2.set_xlim`, just set them to the range you want.

Comment: i want initially load graph last portion.   self.axes2.set_xlim where to set.

Answer (score 2):

QScrollBar inherits a comprehensive set of signals from QAbstractSlider. 
I have used sliderReleased(). because it is emit when the user releases the slider.
To start scroll bar from right position. I initiate scroll bar value (99) Because here i find scroll bar minimal value is (0) and maximum value is (99).

my program :

```
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import num2date, date2num
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ochl as candlestick
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pylab as pl
class MainWindow_code_serarch(object):

    def setup_code_serarch(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1070, 680)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(17, 30, 741, 13))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget1.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget1)
        self.verticalLayout1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout1.setObjectName("verticalLayout1")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(17, 10, 1040, 603))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(100,7.2), dpi=80, facecolor='k')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.canvas.draw()
        # self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # self.scroll_area = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget)
        # self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.canvas)
        # self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.axes, self.axes2 = self.figure.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scroll.setValue(99)


        data = {
            'date': ['2018/10/29','2018/10/30', '2018/11/03', '2018/11/04', '2018/11/05', '2018/11/07', '2018/11/10', '2018/11/11','2018/11/12','2018/11/13'],
            'open': [8824,8824, 8726.31, 8642.14, 8531.51, 8630.25, 8602.50, 8640.22,8202.50, 8610.22],
            'high': [8858,8858, 8748.60, 8551.36, 8653.16, 8476.69, 8630, 8570.56 ,8602.50, 8640.22],
            'low': [8688,8688, 8743.67, 8550.76, 8449.50, 8631.83, 8602.18, 8743.22 ,8502.50, 8540.22],
            'close': [8820,8820, 8747.17, 8550.52, 8553., 8517.10, 8628.78, 8588.52 ,8602.50, 8640.22],
            'volume': [17759.56,17759.56, 120000.17, 18739.52, 38599.50, 16517.10, 17723.78, 15588.52 ,28602.50, 28640.22]
        }
        x = date2num([datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y/%m/%d').date() for d in data['date']])
        t= np.arange(len(data['date']))
        candle_trace = zip(t, data['open'], data['high'], data['low'], data['close'], data['volume'])
        candlestick(self.axes, candle_trace, width=.75, colorup='g', colordown='r')
        self.axes2.plot(t, [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9,6,6,9])
        self.axes.set_position([0.02, 0.37, 0.88, 0.6])
        self.axes2.set_position([0.02, 0.15, 0.88, 0.22])
        self.axes.tick_params(axis='both', color='#ffffff', labelcolor='#ffffff')
        self.axes.yaxis.tick_right()
        self.axes2.tick_params(axis='both', color='#ffffff', labelcolor='#ffffff')
        self.axes2.grid(color='lightgray', linewidth=.5, linestyle=':')
        self.axes.grid(color='lightgray', linewidth=.5, linestyle=':')
        self.axes2.yaxis.tick_right()
        self.axes.autoscale_view()
        self.axes2.autoscale_view()
        self.axes.set_facecolor('#041105')
        self.axes2.set_facecolor('#041105')
        # N = len(dates)
        self.axes.set_xticks(range(0, len((x)), 1))
        self.axes.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(d).strftime('%b-%d') for d in x])
        self.axes.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in x])
        self.axes2.set_xticklabels([mdates.num2date(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in x])
        self.canvas.draw()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 246, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.graphShowCode)
        self.step = .1
        self.setupSlider()

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        # self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OK"))

    def setupSlider(self):
        self.lims = np.array(self.axes2.get_xlim())
        print("limit"+str(self.lims))
        self.scroll.setPageStep(self.step * 100)
        # self.scroll.actionTriggered.connect(self.update)
        self.scroll.sliderReleased.connect(self.update)

        self.update()

    def update(self, evt=None):
        r = self.scroll.value() / ((1 + self.step) * 100)
        l1 = self.lims[0] + r * np.diff(self.lims)
        l2 = l1 + np.diff(self.lims) * self.step
        self.axes2.set_xlim(l1, l2)
        self.axes.set_xlim(l1, l2)
        print(self.scroll.value(), l1, l2)
        self.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MainWindow_code_serarch()
    ui.setup_code_serarch(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: output]