# How to create scrollbar in a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scrollbar, data-visualization

I have a lot of data series (> 1000 bars). For this reason the plot is scaled very small. Do you know how I can activate a **scrollbar in the plt.barh-chart with python?** If I can set a fixed height of the bars then I can scroll through the > 1000 bars. Perhaps you have another solution for me?

[image: plt.barh with scrollbar]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set position for scrollbar with respect to image size.

Kindly refer a below URL:

[Scrollable Bar graph matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791466/scrollable-bar-graph-matplotlib)

Answer (score -2):

Could you provide a reproducible example? Other than that I can just give you plain advice. First of all, ask you whether you are really in need of Youtube/Netflix/etc. 1-10. Because it makes the chart very confusing. I came across the same problem some time ago too and I figured that the Gantt Chart from Plotly, particularly for Python, is a really good solution to make it clearer.
As for your original question:

```
fig= plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
```